# how do Resolve Share button Android Studio errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to make an application for me to use, but I have problems when I will add a share button, can you help me resolve the error

this is my snippet code for syntax share in MainActivity:

```
        // sharebutton start
        ImageView btn_share=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.share_its);
        btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shareIt();
            }
        });
    }
    private void shareIt() {
//sharing implementation here
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJEK TEKS");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEXT TO SHARE ");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "SHARE IT"));
// Sharebutton end



    }
```

complete code in https://pastebin.com/qwD7KtPD

This is my main.xml

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:visible="false"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_laporan"
        android:title="Laporan"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_share"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="@color/bottomlogo"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share" />
```

after i compile to .apk i get error

Comment: Can you add the error stacktrace ?

Comment: This is the resulting error http://prntscr.com/pinlg6

Comment: try reimporting and rebuild project

Comment: It must be somewhere some bracket is missing go through the code and check.

Comment: This item is not allowed in layout xml. 
this should be inside menu.mxl file

Comment: ok, thanks for info, i try to check again and place it in menu @ Swayangjit @Kishan Maurya

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Comment: @kishan maurya no buddy, i follow step in https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433 , no error but if i'm click the button, no respon

Answer (score 0):

Try using ImageButton instead of Imageview since only with ImageButton you can perform actions on clicking it and write further code onto it. Rest of the code seems fine.

You can check on below mentioned link for your reference.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433